# Unexpected token Function : Async Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cloud-foundry

I am having issue deploying a application developed in node js. It uses Docker framework and is being deployed on Pivotal.

On pushing the app to Pivotal I get the following error

> /home/vcap/app/node_modules/popsicle-transport-http/dist/index.js:372
> return async function (req, next) {
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function,

Which prevents the app from starting.

Now I understand that the error can be caused due to the version of node not supporting `async` call. The app is not developed by me but it's upon me to deploy it on Pivotal.

I have ran the following commands to update npm and node

```
npm install -g npm stable
npm install -g node
```

and checked versions

```
npm -v
```

v6.10.2

```
node -v
```

v10.15.1

Then build the solution

```
docker build -t helloworld .
```

Then pushed the app to pivotal which produces the above error.

I have looked at the git page for popsicle and can't see anything been discussed on similar issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the full `cf push` command you're running?

Comment: `cf push <app-name> --no-route`

Comment: Do you also have a manifest file? Are you pushing a docker image? or just app files?

Comment: @DanielMikusa just app files.

Comment: Can you include the full output of `cf push` in your question?